# MediaWiki "Save changes" timeout issue

Tags: php, lua, mediawiki, wamp64, scribunto

So I have MediaWiki installed on my computer (and I'm running it through Wamp64) and it has been working totally fine until today. Essentially, a page I was working on starting timing out when I tried to save edits with the following error:

```
Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 120 seconds exceeded in D:\wamp64\www\pedia\extensions\Scribunto\includes\engines\LuaStandalone\LuaStandaloneEngine.php on line 528
```

I couldn't derive much of anything from the provided stack or individual line numbers so I turned to Google.

After searching I found that it could potentially just be a simple `php.ini` fix, so I opened the `php.ini` file from the WampServer icon menu, changed the maximum execution time (first to 240 and then later to 1000) and tried again. It failed both times multiple times (I restarted the server for both at first, and then restarted my laptop).

I tried saving existing pages with no changes, which took a while, but these processed okay. However, any changes I would make would not work.

Additionally, if I created a new page, it would work fine at around 5,000 characters or less, but no more than that.

The page I was trying to save at first is big (~24,000 characters; but it wasn't much less than that with the previous version, which saved fine (~22,000 characters).

My Wamp server is 3.1.9 64 bit. Apache is 2.4.39; PHP is 7.2.18; MySQL is 8.0.14; and MariaDB is 10.3.14. The MediaWiki version is 1.32.0 (Lua version is 5.1.4). Please let me know if there's any additional information I can provide (and thanks so much for your help)!

Comment: Try using [LuaSandbox](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/LuaSandbox) which is a bit faster.

Comment: @Tgr I'm running MediaWiki on a 64 bit Windows 10 platform... Is it possible to install LuaSandow on Windows?

Comment: Not easily... with enough effort, you could probably compile it yourself.